# How to cache node_modules on Docker build with version?

Tags: node.js, docker

To cache node_modules I add the `package.json` first then I run `npm i` inside docker image.

which is works great. but I also need to have version inside the `package.json`, and each deploy/build I increment the version number.

Because `package.json` has been changed, docker is not cache mode_modules because of it.

How can I cache `node_modules` in this senirio?

```
FROM node

# If needed, install system dependencies here

# Add package.json before rest of repo for caching
ADD package.json /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install

ADD . /app

# If needed, add additional RUN commands here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this cache using `BUILD_VERSION` along with `package.json` version.

```
ARG BUILD_VERSION=0.0.0
```

Set some default value to `BUILD_VERSION`, keep the same value from `BUILD_VERSION` as `package.json` version to ignore the npm installation process.

Suppose you have the version in package.json is `0.0.0` and build version should be `0.0.0` to ignore installation.

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app 
ARG BUILD_VERSION=0.0.0
copy package.json /app/package.json
RUN echo BUILD_VERSION is $BUILD_VERSION  and Package.json version is  $(node -e "console.log(require('/app/package.json').version);")
RUN if [ "${BUILD_VERSION}" != $(node -e "console.log(require('/app/package.json').version);") ];then \
   echo "ARG version and Package.json is different, installing node modules";\
   npm install;\ 
   else \
   echo "npm installation process ignored";\
   fi
```

To ignore npm installation during the build, run build command with

```
docker build --no-cache --build-arg BUILD_VERSION=0.0.0 -t test-cache-image .
```

[image]

Now, if you want to install node_modules just update the run command and it will work as you are expecting but more control as compared to caching track.

```
docker build --no-cache --build-arg BUILD_VERSION=0.0.1 -t test-cache-image .
```

This will install `node_modules` if the `package.json` version did not match with build-version.

[image]

Comment: Well, I was thinking about when my codebase in my app has changed and the npm packages in `package.json` have no change. and when the codebase in my app change then I want to increment a version every time I want to deploy my app. So, my deps have no change and my app are changed, and the version is increment during the build and deploy.
So want can I do to have `node_modules` cached?

Comment: if there is no extra modules in your package.json then `BUILD_VERSION` and `package.json`  version should be same, if you add new package in package.json just update package.json with out passing `BUILD_VERSION` it install new.

Comment: not necessary. what if I fix a bug in my code like `const a = 2` instend of `const a = 1` then I did deploy, the version has change from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 (fix bug) or add develop something new without using any new package from npm. - then my senerio is for increase the version..

Comment: is the screenshot is not clear yet to get you to your problem? if you increase the version the in package.json that is `1.0.1 ` and you do not need to install node modules your build-args will be `BUILD_VERSION=1.0.1` this will avoide installing modules . inshort and simple work keep both value same if you do not want install modules and different value if you want install.